# Making circuit that calculates two's complement of 4 bit number

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

How can I make a circuit that calculates two's complement of a 4-bit number **just by using 5 logic gates** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very straightforward. To create the 2's complement, you need to invert all of the bits of the number, and then add 1 to the result. "Adding one" simply requires a series of half-adders.

Draw out the logic that performs the two steps separately, and then start combining gates and eliminating gates whose inputs and/or outputs are never used.

As a further hint to get you started: what is the relationship between the LSB of the input and the LSB of the output?